# Left outer join doesn't exclude when both the table have null values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, rdbms

I have a requirement where I have to extract data exclusive to the left table. I am using the left outer join for this. But the output extract data that has a null value for the variable used in join condition in both the table which is not expected. Below is the detailed condition,

**TableA**

| id | name | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | math |
| 2 | jack | null |

**TableB**

| id | name | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | john | science |
| 2 | jack | null |

**Query**

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM TableA 
  LEFT JOIN TableB 
    ON a.id = b.id
   AND a.subject = b.subject
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
   AND b.subject IS NULL
```

**Expected output**

| id | name | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | math |

**Actual output**

| id | name | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | math |
| 2 | jack | null |

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` never reduces left table, so you need just `JOIN` for referential integrity or use separate`WHERE a.subject is not null`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in your problem requirement, you seem to need to treat `null` as equal to (other) `null`.

This goes against the definition of `null`. But you can achieve your required result - in the join condition, change

```
and a.subject = b.subject
```

to

```
and (a.subject = b.subject or (a.subject is null and b.subject is null))
```

In Oracle, you can do this more succintly:

```
and decode (a.subject, b.subject, 1) = 1
```

because `decode` was defined intentionally to see two `null` as "equal".

You could do the same for the `id` column, if needed - but assuming it's supposed to be primary key in both tables, you shouldn't need it.

**EDIT** The OP claims that the suggested use of `decode` produces the wrong result, while the explicit use of `or (a.subject is null and b.subject is null)` runs indefinitely on SQL Developer. So in this Edit I will show that the OP's claims are both wrong. (I ran everything on my copy of SQL Developer, so the IDE is not the issue.)

What he is doing, we don't know, but both suggestions are 100% correct for the data provided and the query as given to us (after we add the table aliases, which are missing in the OP's query, and we select just the data from `TableA`).

Test data:

```
create table tablea (id, name, subject) as
  select 1, 'tom' , 'math'    from dual union all
  select 2, 'jack', null      from dual
;

create table tableb (id, name, subject) as
  select 3, 'john', 'science' from dual union all
  select 2, 'jack', null      from dual
;
```

First query and result:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableB b 
    ON a.id = b.id
   AND (a.subject = b.subject or (a.subject is null and b.subject is null))
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
   AND b.subject IS NULL
;

        ID NAME SUBJECT
---------- ---- -------
         1 tom  math
```

Second query and result:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableB b 
    ON a.id = b.id
   AND decode(a.subject, b.subject, 1) = 1
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
   AND b.subject IS NULL
;

        ID NAME SUBJECT
---------- ---- -------
         1 tom  math
```

Comment: I tried both decode and coalesce but still, the null row is present in output and with (a.subject = b.subject or (a.subject is null and b.subject is null)) the query runs indefinitely in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @VinayGowda - then you are doing something wrong. I will add demo to prove that the suggestions I made work perfectly well on the data you provided. Maybe your data is very different, or maybe you are making mistakes in the queries (or both). In any case, your posted query is wrong, because you are using aliases `a` and `b` which you did not define: the tables in the `from` clause are shown as `TableA` and `TableB` without alias. (The `select` also should be `select a.*` rather than `select *` but that is not a syntax error.)